# Can i install ubuntu 14.04 on Intel P4 3gb ddr3 ram?

Tags: 14.04, intel

Well like the title say, i have an old computer, with an Intel Pentium 4 and 3 gb on ram ddr3, but the cuestion still there, can i install ubuntu 14.04? If is true... how much fast or how much lag i'll find?

Answer (score 1):

You have more than enough ram (though ddr3 paired with a Pentium 4 sounds odd), and I would assume your cpu is faster than 700mhz which is the minimum requirement. The only thing you might have to worry about is PAE support. If your computer has PAE you're good to go, if not you'll need to install an Ubuntu derivative like Lubuntu as I believe the derivatives still ship with non-pae kernels by default, but don't quote me on that.

In regards to your question about lag. Unity is a heavy desktop environment. You may experience some lag depending on your cpu specs and graphics card. In that case consider installing Lubuntu which is lighter.

Comment: 700Mhz is for Ubuntu without Unity ( < 11.04 ).

Comment: Yeah i have more ram because use windows and needed the ram, i wanna change mi processor but right now my only option is amd semtron 3000+ (Some like that) but i know that P4 is better for Multi-Task and amd for graphics things

Comment: Information about the graphic card is a must. Unity could be unusable slow when using some cards.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum suggested specs are listed here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements
Based off those specs, you should be fine.

And here is a link to a page with suggested practices for speed improvement on Ubuntu systems, in particular older hardware:
http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks the second page helps me, if i can install ubuntu 14.04 on my pc (Because it isn't on my house) I'll told you my results before and after install the program named on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can always install a more resource friendly version of Ubuntu such as Lubuntu (the same works for Xubuntu and Kubuntu, although Kubuntu is not as lightweight as the other two).

Images can be found here: http://lubuntu.net/ and here http://xubuntu.org/.

or if you already installed regular Ubuntu, just install lubuntu-desktop via the software center or via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

For Xubuntu just do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: added a comment for Kubuntu

Comment: Well i try whit lubuntu some time ago, i like the speed and the response, but to make it light the interface don't have some elements that i love (Like the menu, the format of the shut down button, the task-bar and other). however if it is the only way to use latest ubuntu on my pc i'll do it

Comment: I prefer Unity myself, but sometimes the machine just can't handle it, but as I said, you can just try regular Ubuntu first and if that doesn't work very well you can always easily install Lubuntu (or Xubuntu) afterwards.